# Installing JDK in a FHS-compliant way

Tags: software-installation, fhs, jdk

I'm trying to install JDK on elementaryOS 0.3, but I'd like to do it in a FHS-compliant way. I've read a couple of answers about this topic, and a lot of them state that a program could be installed in `/usr/local/`. I was going to create a *java* folder in `/usr/local`, but before to do that, I started to read the FHS 3. [It said the following](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html#purpose24):

> **4.9.2. Requirements**
>
> The following directories, or symbolic links to directories, must be in /usr/local
>
> **Directory    Description**
>
> 1. bin    Local binaries
> 2. etc    Host-specific system configuration for local binaries
> 3. games  Local game binaries
> 4. include    Local C header files
> 5. lib    Local libraries
> 6. man    Local online manuals
> 7. sbin   Local system binaries
> 8. share  Local architecture-independent hierarchy
> 9. src    Local source code
>
> **No other directories, except those listed below, may be in /usr/local after first installing a FHS-compliant system.**

This means that I have to unzip the JDK file and put, for example, the JDK's bin folder inside of `/usr/local/bin`, JDK's manuals in `/usr/local/man`, and so on with the other folders?

Comment: Why not just install those packages your distro provides?

Comment: Most distributiond install the java packages from their respective repositories (as Braiam suggests) in the `/opt` directory which is FHS compliant... Each user gets their source code in a centralized location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, you have a couple of options.

1. You can install OpenJDK using the `openjdk-7` or `openjdk-8` packages; I'm not sure the latter are available in elementary OS though.
2. You can re-package an Oracle JDK (including JDK 8) using the `java-package` package which is also available in elementary OS. This will give you an FHS-compliant package which will also integrate nicely with the Java alternatives system which is used in Debian derivatives.